# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: error (custom module)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, syntax, expression

When I inspect my page I notice the following warning - I know the module it relates to but don't know specifically what to look for in it - anyone know and able to help guide me to the actual error - ie is it a missing ' or something?

Thanks...

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /delivery-info/
    at se.error (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:13639)
    at se.tokenize (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:21650)
    at se.select (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:22477)
    at Function.se (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:7116)
    at s.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2:2:2230)
    at s.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:25047)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (single-product.min.js?ver=7.4.1:1:876)
    at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:43064)
    at y.handle (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:41048)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.1:2:71659)
```

Comment: It'd be nice to see a bit more of your code which works with URLs (I guess) since "/delivery-info/" this piece of message kind of hints at that direction.

Comment: Hi, it is basically this 0 https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list

I created a delivery rate search based on the above.

Comment: Just a guess, but did you forget to add quotes around '/delivery-info/'? If you surround the string with quotes, it will be treated as a string or URL. However, without quotes, it becomes a regular expression and may cause an error when used as a parameter where a string is expected.

Comment: Hiya Denis - thanks for your help. I have definitely used quotes on every delivery-info instance so it is not that. Only thing I can think of is the script?

I am using this - need to post in two halves as this only allows a limited character reply :(

Comment: ` function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (filter && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

myFunction() `

Comment: Here is the input type I have added at the top (ie the box to search) - 

<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()" placeholder="Delivery Cost Search" title="Delivery Cost">

Comment: It's getting challenging to keep all your code imagined and the w3s example you referencing above works like a charm. I think it is a good time to update your question with some real code you have (ideally using SO code snippets feature) to make sure everyone can see the problem.